# Firewall Rules between GKE and GAE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, firewall

Trying to setup firewall rules between A private cluster on GKE and GAE. The cluster forwards requests to the application in GAE (python3 environment).

The GKE cluster is connected to a NAT service, which has a an external IP. I want to close app engine environment, but only the cluster should be allowed to access GAE.

When implemented a firewall rule (on app engine level and general VPC firewall level) to allow or deny the staticIP of the NAT, the rule does not get implemented. When removed the NAT, the cluster cannot send any request to GAE. Is something missing here?

Important to Note is that our cluster and GAE environment are in different regions. After adding X-Forwarded-For header to the code in GAE, it returned serval IP adresses, one of the cluster node (internal IP) and 2 others that were unfamilier, I did not see the NAT static IP address. Even when I denied both IPs the firewall did allow them to connect.

Comment: Any reason you are trying to use GAE instead of, say, Knative? (there are many similar frameworks for K8s but Knative is from Google and very easy to install on GKE)

Comment: Note that, to allow only the NAT IP to access your App Engine, you need to set the firewall rule at App Engine level, [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/firewall).

Comment: @LundinCast I have tried that but the rule did not seem to apply. I have to note, that our app engine and cluster are in different zones. I used X-Forwarded-For header to inspect through which IPs the traffic is routed. I saw the cluster nodes internal IP, however, the other IPs were unfamiliar. The NAT IP was not included. But if i remove the NAT, the cluster cannot send requests to GAE environment.

Comment: @user13151408 In the question you said different regions but in the comments you said different zones. Could you please specify which one of those statements is correct?

Comment: @ OhHiMark it is different regions, my bad for the confusion

Comment: Do you have [Private Access enabled](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#interaction-pga)? There are [some considerations](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#interaction-pga) for PA when interacting with the GAE fw. What's your config for GAE and Cloud NAT?